# Select value from auto complete field(onchange) using Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, webdriver, onchange

I am trying to select a value in autocomplete field with the code below. On running this code it just highlights the accepted value in the list. But it doesn't select that value.

```
WebElement client_name_field= driver.findElement(By.id("txtSearchQuote"));
        client_name_field.sendKeys("a");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement client_name=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/ul"));
        List<WebElement> option_to_select= client_name.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        for(WebElement client_name_list: option_to_select)
        {
            if(client_name_list.getText().equals("Biological Dynamics"))
            {
                client_name_list.click();
                System.out.println(""+client_name_list.getText());

            }
        }
```

Comment: how does related HTML look before you enter value and after it is filled?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select from a selectbox you should try this:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("li"))).selectByVisibleText("Biological Dynamics");
```

If you add an id or name attribute in the HTML it will make it easier to change the specific field you want.
This will find the selectbox and select the specific text you want.